# Combine two 3 byte integers, and one 2 byte integer into one 8 byte integer

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

Trying to store three integers into one to use for a hash, and decode back into their original values.

The variables:

```
x = 3 byte integer (Can be negative)
z = 3 byte integer (Can be negative)
y = 2 byte integer (Cannot be negative)
```

My current code - doesn't work with negatives:

```
long combined = (y) | (((long) z) << 16) | ((((long) x)) << 40);
int newX = (int) (combined >> 40); // Trim off 40 bits, leaving the heading 24
int newZ = (int) ((combined << 24) >> (40)); // Trim off 24 bits left, and the 16 bits to the right
int newY = (int) ((combined << 48) >> 48); // Trim off all bits other then the first 16
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work for negatives because your "3 byte integer" or "2 byte integer" is actually a regular 4-byte int. If the number is negative, all the highest bits will be set to "1"; if you binary-or the numbers together, these high 1 bits will overwrite the bits from the other numbers.

You can use bit-masking to encode the number correctly:

```
long combined = (y & 0xffff) | (((long) z & 0xffffff) << 16) | ((((long) x & 0xffffff)) << 40);
```

This will cut off the high-bits outside the 16 or 24 bit range that you're interested in.

The decoding already works fine, because the bit-shifting that you perform takes care of sign-extension.